# Turn off laptop display and have monitor

Tags: multiple-monitors, laptop, display, monitor, hdmi

My laptop display has stopped working and is unfixable!

Anyway, I got a full HD monitor and plugged that into the HDMI port of the laptop. I have changed the power settings so that I can close the lid and still have the monitor on, and this all works.

However because it is on "mirror displays", I cannot get the full 1080p resolution that the monitor supports, and when I turn off mirror displays and switch off the laptop screen, the monitor will also switch off!

I'm really stuck, as I can only get the monitor to display its full resolution if I have it with the laptop screen turned on, and I dont want this because (as the laptop display does not work) things get lost on that side of the screen.

HELP.

(Dell Studio 1537
Monitor is Samsung SA300
Connected through HDMI
Ubuntu 11.10)

Comment: Open the dash with "windows" key and then type "displays", hit enter, and in that window you can turn off the laptop's screen.

Comment: Didn't really look this thru but maybe some of this links can help you. <http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1309247> <http://www.thetechrepo.com/main-articles/502-how-to-change-the-primary-monitor-in-ubuntu-or-other-linux-distributions>

Comment: Hi Ryan, is this still an issue. I had the same problem with my Dad's HP laptop. The solution was found after updating to 12.04+. He is on 13.10 right now and this issue is not found there.

Answer (score 1):

Try installing [arandr](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/arandr/) ,in your system as it gives you gui , which is easy to mange

[image].

In the outputs tab you can easily turnoff your laptop's display (LVDS) and keep your monitor's one (VGA or in your scenario it might be HDMI1) as your primary display and save the layout. Add the following layout script into your startup menu, so when next time you login to your desktop it works without any extra inconvenience.

Answer (score 1):

Things have changed a lot since Ubuntu 11.10 which I read you are running. Please consider upgrading to 12.04 or 14.04, where multi monitor setups work quite nicely:

[image: Screenshot]